# while calling Apex REST class, getting response "Could not find a match for URL /CallREST1","errorCode":"NOT_FOUND"}]"

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, http, httprequest

here is my APEX REST class code

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/CallREST1')
```

global with sharing class CallREST
 { 
      @HttpPost
      global static String createNewCase(String companyName) 
      {
         System.debug('COMPANY: '+companyName);
         return 'done';
      }
 }

my HTTP request code is

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + accessToken);
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
req.setHeader('accept','application/json');
 req.setEndpoint(instance_url+'/services/apexrest/CallREST1');
 req.setBody('{"companyName":"GenePoint"}');
 req.setMethod('POST');
 HttpResponse res =new Http().send(req);
```

please point me out where i am wrong..
i don't have any namespace, package name.
i have tried with appending Organization name or Organization ID , as i found from somewhere to try all this things..
any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you calling WebService from same Org to same Org?

Comment: @Ganesh i am calling REST web service from other org.

Comment: Check the authorization header that should be `Bearer ACCESSTOKEN`

Comment: Check whats the variable instance_url is returning?

Comment: @MartinBorthiry, I have tried with Bearer also. but it didn't worke,same issue again.

Comment: @MohithKumar, instance_url is returning instanceURL of source org.i am getting instanceURL from the returned response, and using same here.

Comment: @MartinBorthiry, Hi can you tell me when to use OAuth OR Bearer, OR provide me any link where can i get clarify.

Comment: @Ankuli Please test through workbench once ?

Comment: @MohithKumar from workbench its working fine, that's why i am getting confuse more..because as with workbench i am able to access my rest service class, means my REST classs code is fine, there is problem in http request code.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue. According to Rich Unger, the solution may be to "Run All Tests" or click the "Compile All Classes" link in the Apex class list. Take a look at [this blog post](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2012/02/28/apex-rest-service-not-found/) and the comments at the bottom of the page for more info.